# jquery and wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming

i am having difficulty making my jquery functions operate within wordpress.

can anyone help out with why these should work normally but not in wordpress???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have to load the script using `wp_enque_script`. You can find the documentation for this function and for loading scripts in WordPress in general at the [codex page for `wp_enque_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). Furthermore, I found an article on [Using jQuery with WordPress](http://themocracy.com/2009/04/using-jquery-with-wordpress/) that provides sample code for the loading of the script and then the use of it.

If you look at the Codex documentation, it says:

> The jQuery library included with Wordpress loads in ["no conflict"](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) mode.

So to be able to use the `$()` function as usual, you have to do

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

For an example of what that looks like, look at step 2 of the Themocracy article linked above.

I'm pretty sure you'll be fine with these resources, hope they help.

Comment: Hi there,

have investigated this, cheers, one extra problem was that i was calling jquery from the goolge cdn not the wordpress built in version which starts in NoConflict mode. used 

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 



to call this and it finally works!

Cheers.