# Using jquery inside the wp_editor

Tags: jquery, wordpress

here's the scenario:

I'm creating a page in the wordpress admin. I created a page called Contact Us, in the editor or WYSIWYG I made a form and a button. I want to use $.post in submitting the form.

Inside the editor:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="txt"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

In the page.php, I included  this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        alert('save');
    });
});
```

But there's an error in the firebug console that say's: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

What's wrong with this? Or is this even possible?

Comment: You forgot the closing `'` after `#btn`.

Comment: ok. i did not copy paste into here, so pardon for the typos.

Comment: No problem, just making sure that it wouldn't generate a syntax error. On topic, yes it's possible. Make sure jQuery is included on your page -- I don't remember exactly, but I think WP has a built-in jQuery lib somewhere.. I'll check that, even though I'd rather include it through the Google CDN.

Comment: This question seems to cover all I know about jQuery-WP, check if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/952262/1331430

Comment: yeah. how silly of me. there was no jquery included in the page.php. *sigh

Comment: @FabrícioMatté  you can answer this post man, and I'll choose it as the correct answer. So it can boost your rep here, even just for a little. Think of it as a thank you for your response. :)

Comment: Did you get the script to work already? Just including the jQuery lib?

Comment: yes. by just including the lib. everthing is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Means that the jQuery namespace is not defined, it happens because you either forgot to include the jQuery lib, the client browser couldn't find it in the specified address or the client browser is not compatible with jQuery (that error shows up on IE 5.5 even when the address is right).

Also, if you're using WP's embedded jQuery library, you can't use `$` to reference jQuery in the global scope as WP automatically sets it to [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Taken from the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers):

> Note: The jQuery library included with WordPress loads in "no
>   conflict" mode. This is to prevent compatibility problems with other
>   javascript libraries that WordPress can load.

You can create a closure to alias `$` as `jQuery` then:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

To use the embedded library, you should also include your scripts using [`wp_enque_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952305/1331430) for more detailed info.

Obviously, you can also include it from the Google CDN and skip all those `wp_enque_script` and closure guidelines by adding/echoing the script tags directly which is what I'd personally do, but I didn't say that! `:)`